# Is two years enough for panel data analysis?

Tags: r, regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing, panel-data

I have around 800 companies for only two years period. However, around 200 of them have only one year observation. Is it still possible to conduct panel data analysis with such data 
Thank you

Comment: I think this all depends on the goal of your analysis? By panel model I am assuming you mean a longitudinal auto regressive path model? Can you please add more information about the intent of your analysis?

Comment: Yes, but you will only be able to use companies with 2 periods of data.  Once you limit the sample, it will work.